# Groupby a pandas dataframe and create a new column by transform

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform, apply

Imagine we have a DataFrame like df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('AL', 2, 0.3),
                      ('WY', 4, 0.2),
                     ('CO', 1, 0.9),
                     ('WY', 6, 0.2),
                    ('CO', 6, 0.1),
                     ('CO', 8, 0.3),
                   ('CO', 3, 0.2),
                   ('TX', 2, 0.4),
                   ('AL', 4, 0.4)],
                   columns=('ST', 'Case', 'Prob'))
```

I want to split this dataframe into separate states and run a diff() on Case column. I have done this so far:
I first sort by state and case (I need case to be ordered). Then groupby 'ST' and trying to use a function called Test to do the diff() but this dsnt work. I have been reading documents and I find out confusion on how to use transform and apply. Any help? thanks

```
def test(x):
    return x.diff()

def daily_windowed_avg(df):
   
    df= df.sort_values(by=['ST', 'Case'], ascending=[True, True])
    
    df['Case diff'] = df.groupby(df['ST']).transform(lambda x: test(x), axis=1)
    
    return df
    
daily_windowed_avg(df)
```

Comment: `transform` is really meant when your function returns a single value per group. In this case `Series.diff` returns a Series so there's no need for transform and you can just use `SeriesGroupBy.diff`: `df['Case diff'] = df.groupby('ST')['Case'].diff()`

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: 1. You don't need to create your own specific functions in pandas when pandas methods already exist 2. Avoid lambda x in favor of pandas methods if one can solve your problem. Use the answer ALollz has provided. There isn't a better way.